# Arduino joining two int's

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Hello I have two variables
timer1hh = 9 
timer1mm = 7

I convert them to strings, join them together and I get the "97" using the code below:

```
String string1= String(timer1hh); 
String string2= String(timer1mm);
String string3;         

string3=string1+string2;      
Serial.println(string3);
```

Thats fine but i want to add a leading 0 if its below 10 so it would look like.

"0907"

so eventually i want to be able to do an "if" between "0907" and say "2034" do this type of thing. Im totally blagged with the sprintf using "%02" and its simply not working for me.

Any help would be great.

Pete

Comment: Not a solution, but it is far easier to compare two numbers than it is to compare two strings that hold numbers. If I were you, I wouldn't be converting to strings, but would instead convert the two times to minutes since midnight. This then makes comparisons a breeze. I.e 9.07am would be (9*60)+7 and 8.34pm would be (20*60)+34. Far easier to compare against 547 and 1234 than "0907" and "2034" - Also, printf doesn't use "%02", it uses "%02d" - You could print a time in one go thusly: `printf("%02d%02d", t1h, t1m);`

Answer (score 0):

see this sketch:

```
void setup() {

    int timer1hh = 9, timer1mm = 7;

    Serial.begin(9600);
    //String string1= String(timer1hh); 
    //String string2= String(timer1mm);
    //String string3;         

    char out1[5];
    sprintf(out1,"%.2d%.2d", timer1hh,timer1mm  );
    String string3(out1);

    //string3=string1+string2;      
    Serial.println(string3);
}

void loop() {}
```

serial output: `0907`